# Partial sort algorithm

Tags: algorithm, perl

I'm quite new to perl. So, I'm sorry if there an obvious answer. 
My question: Is there an built-in alternative in Perl for std::partial_sort in C++. Or at least can you recommend me a CPAN module which implements this algorithm?
Thank you in advance.

Comment: The only reason I can think of to use a partial sort like that is for code optimisation. Is that what you want it for? If so, then have you made sure the sort is truly the bottleneck in your process?

Comment: Yes, I want to do an optimisation. I have an array of values which is quite big and I need only top 10 values. After replacing quicksort by partial_sort I expect about 20% performance growth.

Comment: Then I suggest you code a simple selection sort. Maintain a list of the top ten values, and iterate through your data updating the top ten as you go. Let me know if you need a code example.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks like what you want is `Sort::Key::Top`.

I have written a Perl selection sort as I described, and while it turns out to be better than four times faster than just using `sort` on the whole list and choosing the top ten, the `top` function from `Sort::Key::Top` is more than twice as fast again.

Here is my code and the results. It tests with the list of four-character patterns from `AAAA` to `ZZZZ` - nearly half a million.

```perl
use strict;
use warnings;

use List::Util 'shuffle';
use Sort::Key::Top 'top';
use Benchmark 'timethese';

srand(0);
my @list = shuffle 'AAAA' .. 'ZZZZ';

timethese(100, {

  'Sort::Key::Top' => sub {
    my @topten = top 10 => @list;
  },

  'Pure Perl' => sub {

    my @topten;

    for my $item (@list) {
      if (@topten and $item lt $topten[-1]) {
        my $i = $#topten-1;
        --$i while $i >= 0 and $topten[$i] gt $item;
        splice @topten, $i+1, 0, $item;
        pop @topten if @topten > 10;
      }
      elsif (@topten < 10) {
        push @topten, $item;
      }
    }
  },

  'Perl sort' => sub {
    my @topten = (sort @list)[0..9];
  },
});
```

**output**

```
Benchmark: timing 100 iterations of Perl sort, Pure Perl, Sort::Key::Top...
     Perl sort: 46 wallclock secs (45.76 usr +  0.11 sys = 45.86 CPU) @  2.18/s (n=100)
     Pure Perl: 11 wallclock secs (10.84 usr +  0.00 sys = 10.84 CPU) @  9.22/s (n=100)
Sort::Key::Top:  4 wallclock secs ( 3.99 usr +  0.13 sys =  4.12 CPU) @ 24.28/s (n=100)
```

Comment: note that S::K::T may use a different algorithm for top 6 or less.

Answer (score 1):

A quick search turns up [`Sort::Key::Top`](https://metacpan.org/module/Sort%3a%3aKey%3a%3aTop) but there may be other choices.

Comment: It's not really perverse. 1) It's an in-place sort, so it's primarily a side-effect, and 2) it could be useful if you're only displaying X elements now, but might want to display Y more later.

Comment: Does S::K::T have the same complexity characteristics as `partial_sort`?

Comment: no clue; the SKT code has so many different modes its hard to tell (and partial_sort is a specification, not an algorithm).  I see now the `*part` subs include the non-selected values at the end.

Comment: `partial_sort` may not promise an algorithm, but it does promise performance characteristics. That's the whole point of using it.

Comment: It looks to me like SKT in some cases sorts the whole list using quicksort (O(n log n)), and in some cases (sometimes when 6 or fewer are to be selected) does a partial insertion sort (O(n*m)); I don't see any performance characteristics *promised* for partial_sort, but I do see assertions that it uses introsort (O(n log m), I think).

Comment: heapsort, I mean, not introsort